# Android SDK compatibility for different modules from the Design Support Library

Tags: android, material-design

I would like to create a bottom navigation in my application and I found an easy way with **Bottom Navigation** provided from **Material Design**.

My only problem is that I want the application to run on **Android SDK 23** and I can see that Bottom Navigation from Material requires `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'` which requires `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'`. Currently I'm using `23.4.0` and I'm assuming that changing this will make my application to work on Android SDK 25 and up only.

Is this correct?

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself? It's a very easy test case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. That is not correct.
There's a big important difference between compile version and minimum version. This change is only in compile version.

- Compile version is the version your compiler will look at the moment it's compiling your code. That is only for the compiler to know which methods are available on the device. For example, to know that an Activity has a `findViewById` and that a ViewGroup have a `addView`. As long you don't use a method that is higher that your minimum it makes no difference.
- Minimum version that is the one you're telling the Google Play and the Android system the minimum where your app can be installed and that it should work fine. That's the one that limits which version to it can be installed.

For more on that I suggest you to read the official training materials here https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html and more specific the section "Check the System Version" https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html#CheckVersion

Comment: I can see that the Bottom Navigation View has been added to version 25 of the Design Support Library. But from what i understand this doesn't mean that it won't work on lower version of the Android SDK. Where i can find the minimum android SDK compatibility for the different modules from the Design Support Library? @AlexGuerra I think you may know the answer to this too.

Comment: Easiest way is to put your project to minimum 4 and wait for the compilation error. But this should give some insight too https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html "Note: The minimum SDK version has been increased to 14"

Comment: Great, thanks :) I will generalise the title. This may help someone else learning Android and wondering the same things about compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry, you refer to `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0` that´s just your dependency, so first at all

1.- If you want to use `'com.android.support:design:25.0.0` you should use at least building version 25:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
```

2.- Your app works with `'com.android.support:design:25.0.0` if you defined in your gradle a minimun SDK or target SDK less than 25:

```
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 25
```

Now look this gradle, is from an app that works on API 19 and the Bottom Navigation View works fine

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "**********"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```